# Resizing Ubuntu Partition with GParted, dual booting with windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

When I first installed Ubuntu, I allocated ~200 GB of space for Ubuntu, but its way more than I need. If I use gparted to resize the size of the partition down to say 100 GB, will the 100GB be usable for my Windows partition immediately or do I have to take additional steps to reallocate that 100GB into my Windows partition, and if yes what should I do specifically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to resize your windows partition to take in the extra 100GB, or create a NTFS partition from that free space.